# Text To Speech service isn't started in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying make such application which speak automatically when the image loaded it self.
I had tried a single application (example)  of TTS which is working properly but this code gives me 
My Code is Text To Speech service isn't started.

```
public class show_image extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

Intent mIntent;
String value;
ImageView mImageView;
private TextToSpeech tts;
int j;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String name = b.getString("name");
    j = name.toCharArray()[0];

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    tts.speak("Welcome", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    switch (j) {
    case 65:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a);
        tts.speak(name + " for Apple", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // "Saying:" + name + " for Apple", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();
        tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH);
        break;
    case 66:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.b);
        tts.speak(name + "for Bluetooth", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 67:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.c);
        tts.speak(name + "for Chat", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 68:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.d);
        tts.speak(name + "for Download", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 69:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.e);
        tts.speak(name + "for E Mail", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 70:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.f);
        tts.speak(name + "for Facebook", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 71:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.g);
        tts.speak(name + "for Google", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 72:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.h);
        tts.speak(name + "for Hewlwtt Packard", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
                null);
        break;
    case 73:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.i);
        tts.speak(name + "for Iphone", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 74:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.j);
        tts.speak(name + "for Java", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 75:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.k);
        tts.speak(name + "for kingston", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 76:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.l);
        tts.speak(name + "for Laptop", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 77:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.m);
        tts.speak(name + "for Messenger", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 78:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.n);
        tts.speak(name + "for Nero", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 79:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.o);
        tts.speak(name + "for Orkut", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 80:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.p);
        tts.speak(name + "for Picassa", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 81:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.q);
        tts.speak(name + "for Quick Heal", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 82:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.r);
        tts.speak(name + "for Ram", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 83:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.s);
        tts.speak(name + "for Server", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 84:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.t);
        tts.speak(name + "for Twitter", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 85:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.u);
        tts.speak(name + "for Usb", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 86:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.v);
        tts.speak(name + "for Vista", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 87:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.w);
        tts.speak(name + "for WiFi", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 88:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);
        tts.speak(name + "for XP", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 89:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.y);
        tts.speak(name + "for Youtube", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    case 90:
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.z);
        tts.speak(name + "for Zorpia", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, RESULT_OK);

    final Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(10000);
                finish();
                // this.destroy();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
    t1.start();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            // success, create the TTS instance
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        } else {
            // missing data, install it
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent
                    .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }

}

public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Write and Listen engine is initialized & Ready",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.shutdown();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please take a look to the solution I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786730/447558

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `OnCreate` You have Written this code,

```
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this); 
    tts.speak("Welcome", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); 
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

At that time Engine is not installed so it Gives error and Quit and never goes to install the Engine,

So First task to do in `OnCreate` should be,

```
    Intent checkIntent = new Intent(); 
    checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA); 
    startActivityForResult(checkIntent, RESULT_OK);
```

Which you are doing long after and trying to `speak` before it's installed

So write that intent for Engine Check as first line in onCreate.Everything else is Fine I see.