# Text to Speech not playing sound for first time, but playing for the next time

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using this kind of text to speech in one of my class in my app(Code edited to show outlook & exact requirement.). I will show some content on my view & if we click the button , I want to play the sound that is by using this texttospeech engine... But for **First time it is not playing the sound. From the next click onwards the TEXTTOSPEECH engine is working nicely**

Iwant to know how to overcome this issue....

```
public class LearnActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

AudioManager audioManager;
float volume;

TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_learn);

   textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(0.95f);

       method();
}
   public void method(){
      bt.setonClickListener(new onClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
                        playSound(datasource.getItemSound);                  
              }

        });

      }
   public void playSound(String sound){
         textToSpeech.speak(sound,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
         }   

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

**NOTE:- This also meet my Requirement, How to play sound from TEXTTOSPEECH engine directly without using any onClicks etc.,...** because I also wants to play a startup sound that too with Android's Text-To-Speech engine only...

Comment: Please take a look to the solution I posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23786730/447558

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I made that app with mediaplayer only, so I don't need now. But I'l surely check it later time, as it is a good topic and I need to cover it.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are clicking the button before the engine is ready.

You have to check if the TTS engine has successfully initialized on your `onInit()` method and enable/disable the play button accordingly.

Assuming that `bt` in your code is some sort of `View` that has [`setEnabled(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) method:

```
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    bt.setEnabled(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS);
}
```

You always have to assume that the engine has not been initialized and hence keep your play button disabled by default.

Comment: ok Thanks for reply, but I want to ask a question first , means the tts sound should play at start of the app without any clicks....As it is working fine on  the next button click itself...

Comment: What was the question again?

Comment: ok leave that, I just wanna play a startup-kinda sound with tts...Just at the start of the activity I am calling a method and Sound in that method should be played.After that only I have the click mechanisms....

Comment: Even in that case, you have to call `speak` after the engine has successfully initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I used RXJava to make a class that solves this problem. If your TTS engine is not ready when you want to use the speak method it will wait for the engine to get ready and then speaks the given string.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Pair;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class Pronunciation {

    private TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
    private int languageResult;
    private boolean noError;
    private final String errorMessage="Something went wrong with your text to speech engine";
    private PublishSubject<Boolean> engineIsReady=PublishSubject.create();
    private PublishSubject<Pair<String,Integer>> speakObservable=PublishSubject.create();
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable=new CompositeDisposable();

    public Pronunciation(Context context) {
        textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(context, status -> {

            if (status!=TextToSpeech.ERROR){
               languageResult=  textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
               engineIsReady.onNext(true);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context,errorMessage
                        ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        });

        if (languageResult==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA||languageResult== TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
            noError =false;
            Toast.makeText(context,errorMessage
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else { noError =true;}


        compositeDisposable.add( Observable.combineLatest(speakObservable, engineIsReady,
                (stringIntegerPair, aBoolean) -> stringIntegerPair)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(pair->{

                    if (noError)
                        textToSpeech.speak( (pair).first
                                ,(pair).second,null,null);
                }));


    }


    public void speak(String text,int queueMode){

        speakObservable.onNext(new Pair<>(text,queueMode));

    }

    public void stop(){
        if (textToSpeech!=null){
            textToSpeech.stop();
            textToSpeech.shutdown();
        }
        compositeDisposable.clear();
    }
}
```

first add RxJava dependency in your Gradle file

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
```

Then create an instance of this class in the onCreate method of your activity or fragment.Now you can pass the string and queue mode to the speak method.

```
pronunciation.speak("Hi", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH));
```

Don't forget to call the stop method in onDestroy or onDetach to avoid memory leak

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    pronunciation.stop();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should write your program ...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

  TextToSpeech t1;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    t1=new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);   
  }/////on creat

  protected void onDestroy() {
    if(t1!=null) {
      t1.stop();
      t1.shutdown();
      t1=null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  public void onInit(int arg0) {
      t1.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
  }

}//mainactivity
```

Add this command when button is clicked or everywhere you want to speak text.

```
t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Just Put Delay For 5 Second And It's Working without any button Click**

```
public class Final_Text_To_Speech_Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

private TextToSpeech tts; // For Text to Speech
CardView ScanProduct, SearchProduct;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    init();

    // Just Put Delay For 5 Second And It's Working without any button Click
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            SpeakOutOnce("Welcome to Text To Speech Application");
        }
    }, 5000);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}


public void init() {

    ScanProduct = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.scan_product);
    SearchProduct = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.search_product);


    // Search On Button Click
    ScanProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            speakOut("You have Just pressed Scan  Option");
        }
    });


    SearchProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            speakOut("You have Just pressed Search Option ");
        }
    });


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

    int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
        } else {
            speakOut("");
        }
    } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


private void speakOut(String text) {

    tts.setPitch(1.0f); //Normal Pitch
    tts.setSpeechRate(0.7f); // 1.0 is Normal speech Rate
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}


private void SpeakOutOnce(String text) {

    if (tts != null) {
        tts.setPitch(1.0f); //Normal Pitch
        tts.setSpeechRate(0.7f); // 1.0 is Normal speech Rate
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

}